# Phonegap - Access Application Installed Directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am building and Hybrid Application, that will run on Android and iOS platform, My application has a feature for downloading content from web server and then use the same for loading the GUI in respective platform, now my question is, how can i access the application installed directory where my application is installed, so I can have a control over the content.

I know how this can be done in Adobe AIR, but I am very new to this Arena, any help will be really very helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
RS.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't know where your application is installed to download and save files and to use them in application. All that you have to know - where is folder for your application data (including downloaded/created files).

Have a look at http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html

According to docs, you can operate with fileSystem.root directory (create/modify/delete files and folders in it). On Android, fileSystem.root is usually SD Card root directory, while on iOS it is separate "sandbox" folder for each application.

Comment: What if i want to use some assets (xml/images) from the installed folder along with the downloaded folder?

Comment: @user1310823 you can include stylesheets, images and javascripts from assets folder to your html files using relative path. You can also navigate between pages, which are in your assets folder, in the same way. And you can read xml-file and use it as node's tree using javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, my requirement is to load all assets from external source, as package will be dynamically loading data. Means, application will download the package and then use that content for rendering application UI, so application has flexibility for loading different data based on user login.

Comment: @user1310823 yes, i understand, but i still suppose that you should download files (images, html, css, js, xml) to application data folder and then read and use them (by including to page or by using data from them) from application core. For example, for downloaded image you can simply get its full path and add to page <img src="full path"> . For xml file, you can read it by JS and use as an object.